# Google maps API - JavaScript vs Flash - what's faster?

Tags: google-maps

I draw on the map about a thousand of simple polygons using JavaScript API V3 
I'm not so happy about performance, especially on IE - it takes about 90 seconds to draw all polygons and the map became hardly responsive

There is any chance Flash API deals with a large amount of polygons better then JavaScript?

Comment: Javacript engines are likely to get faster, Flash plugin creators are too busy fixing holes (or they should be). Also, no flash on many phones, concentrate on making your JS code more efficient.

Comment: I agree with Emyr's comments, and also I'd suggest you consider that a whole bunch of people out there do not have Flash, (the Pest), installed in their computers, (including myself). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Maps API for Flash will generally handle a large amount of polygons better than JS.

You can also get some strategies for improving performance from this talk, given at Google I/O 2009:

- Video:
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zI8at1EmJjA
- Slides:
  http://docs.google.com/Present?skipauth=true&docid=dggjrx3s_325gr9vthfq